# How do I update the section component configuration?

Tags: 8, nodes, configuration, layout-builder

How to update a component in the node's layout builder? I  have used the following code.

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$layout = $node->get('layout_builder__layout');
$sections = $layout->getSections();
foreach ($sections as $key => $section) {
      $components = $section->getComponents();
      foreach ($components as $component) {
        if ($component instanceof SectionComponent && $component->getPluginId() === 'myplugin_id') {
          $configurations = $component->get('configuration');
          $configurations['label_display'] = "0";
          $component->setConfiguration($configurations);
        }
      }
}
```

But now I don't know how to update the section and layout of the node.

Because `$section->setComponent($component)` is a protected method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it like this.

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$layout = $node->get('layout_builder__layout')->getValue();
$sections = $layout->getSections();

foreach ($sections as $key => $section) {
  $components = $section->getComponents();
  foreach ($components as $component) {
    if ($component instanceof SectionComponent && $component->getPluginId() === 'myplugin_id') {
       $configurations = $component->get('configuration');
       $configurations['label_display'] = "0";
       $component->setConfiguration($configurations);
    }
  }
}

$node->set('layout_builder__layout', $layout);
$node->save();
```

For Drupal 9 (Other way around):

```
$nid = 1;
$node = Node::load($nid);
$layout = $node->get('layout_builder__layout')->getValue();

if (!empty($layout)) {
  foreach ($layout as $section) {
    if (isset($section['section']) && $section['section']->getLayoutId() == 'mylayout_id') {
      $components = $section['section']->getComponents();
      foreach ($components as $component) {
        if ($component instanceof SectionComponent && $component->getPluginId() === 'myplugin_id') {
          $configurations = $component->get('configuration');
          $configurations['label_display'] = "0";
          $component->setConfiguration($configurations);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$node->set('layout_builder__layout', $layout);
$node->save();
```

Comment: Perhaps API has changed: Call to a member function getSections() on array